# Page redirecting before asynchronous Javascript loads

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, asynchronous, mixpanel

I'm trying to make a redirect page that tracks the loading of that page with `mixpanel.track`

The problem is, the page redirects before the async javascript has time to download and run. What do I do?

[Here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0cb37af7014ec43f8997) is my code.

Edit: I'm putting the code in the question.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>

<!-- start Mixpanel --><script type="text/javascript">(function(f,b){if(!b.__SV){var a,e,i,g;window.mixpanel=b;b._i=[];b.init=function(a,e,d){function f(b,h){var a=h.split(".");2==a.length&&(b=b[a[0]],h=a[1]);b[h]=function(){b.push([h].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0)))}}var c=b;"undefined"!==typeof d?c=b[d]=[]:d="mixpanel";c.people=c.people||[];c.toString=function(b){var a="mixpanel";"mixpanel"!==d&&(a+="."+d);b||(a+=" (stub)");return a};c.people.toString=function(){return c.toString(1)+".people (stub)"};i="disable track track_pageview track_links track_forms register register_once alias unregister identify name_tag set_config people.set people.set_once people.increment people.append people.track_charge people.clear_charges people.delete_user".split(" ");
for(g=0;g<i.length;g++)f(c,i[g]);b._i.push([a,e,d])};b.__SV=1.2;a=f.createElement("script");a.type="text/javascript";a.async=!0;a.src="//cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2.2.min.js";e=f.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];e.parentNode.insertBefore(a,e)}})(document,window.mixpanel||[]);
mixpanel.init("9f85e6edf009562d5ac2c944b0da6398");mixpanel.track("CBhopID_x3cw17x1h")</script><!-- end Mixpanel -->

<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<meta content="1;url=http://e20f07o0yd5b2re0-x3cw17x1h.hop.clickbank.net/" http-equiv="refresh" />

<script type="text/javascript">
window.location.href = "http://e20f07o0yd5b2re0-x3cw17x1h.hop.clickbank.net/"
</script>

<title>Redirecting...</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>If you are not redirected automatically, follow <a href="http://e20f07o0yd5b2re0-x3cw17x1h.hop.clickbank.net/">this link.</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

[mixpanel.track()](https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/javascript-full-api-reference) has callback option which will be called after tracking event, you need to use it, on callback you could redirect to some location, place your `window.location` code inside the callback function, like:

```
mixpanel.track("CBhopID_x3cw17x1h", {}, function() {
   window.location.href = "http://e20f07o0yd5b2re0-x3cw17x1h.hop.clickbank.net/";
});
```